# How to Exclude a Specific Folder from TypeScript's Strict Type Checking in an Angular Project?

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I'm working on an Angular project with a strict type checking enabled `"strict": true` in `tsconfig.json`. The project structure includes a folder named `3rdparty` within `src/app/shared/`, which contains third-party TypeScript code that I don't have control over. This code is not compatible with strict type checking, and I want to exclude it from the strict checks without affecting the rest of the project.

I tried to create a separate tsconfig file `tsconfig.non-strict.json` with `"strict": false` inside the `3rdparty` folder. However, I am not sure how to integrate this into the Angular CLI's build process so that it respects the non-strict settings for just this folder.

Additionally, when I run `ng serve`, the Angular CLI outputs strict type checking errors that originate from within the 3rdparty folder, despite my attempts to exclude it from strict checks.

Comment: Have you tried your main `tsconfig.json` target the 3rdParty folder and a tsconfig inside it extend from your main?

Comment: Is the 3rd party code an Angular library? Is it pre-compiled? Sounds like you might be able to make an Angular library out of it where it could have a separate tsconfig that's non-strict, and import it into your main application.